# How to pass variable from one ajax function to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am developing a shopping cart using codeigniter and ajax. now i am facing a problem in ajax section. I need to pas a variable from  one ajax function to other

Here is my ajax function I have the id in `$(".product_add").click(function(event)` function i need to get the same in `$(".view_cart").click(function(event)` function

```js
$(".view_cart").click(function(event) {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax_controller/view_cart")?>',
    data: {
      id: '1'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#cart_container").html(response);
      $("#myModal_cart").modal('show');
    }
  }); /* Aajx */
});


$(".product_add").click(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  alert(id);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax_controller1/product_add")?>',
    data: {
      id: '1'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#cart_container").html(response);
      $("#myModal_cart").modal('show');
    }
  }); /* Aajx */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="product_add">pro Items</a></li>
<a href="#" id="edit_product" data-id="<?php echo $fea['product_id'];?>" name="id" data-text="Add To Cart" class="my-cart-b item_add add_to_cart">Add To Cart</a>
```

Comment: You can temporarily save your required data to a hidden field when your first ajax method execute, then when your second ajax method called, you can get your data from hidden field.

Comment: You can add as some data attribute in `.view_cart`. This will be something like whenever there is a click in product add, you will have `var id = $(this).data('id'); $(".view_cart").data('product_id', id);` and you can access it as `$(".view_cart").data('product_id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a variable like

```
var globalId = 0;
```

and then

```
$(".product_add").click(function(event) {
var id=$(this).data('id'); 
globalId = id;
}

$(".view_cart").click(function(event) {
  var currentId = globalId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just modify above answer
You just create global variable on first ajax call using jquery "Window"

```
$(".product_add").click(function(event) {
var id=$(this).data('id'); 
window.new_id = id;
}
```

and use it where you want to use in your pages

```
$(".view_cart").click(function(event) {
  var currentId = new_id;
}
```